# Web Scraping (in R?)

Tags: r, html-parsing, web-scraping

I want to get the names of the companies in the middle column of [this](http://www.consumercomplaints.in/bysubcategory/mobile-service-providers/page/1.html) page (written in bold in blue), as well as the location indicator of the person who is registering the complaint (e.g. "India, Delhi", written in green). Basically, I want a table (or data frame) with two columns, one for company, and the other for location. Any ideas?

Comment: What language you want to use?

Comment: Preferably R. But Python or PHP is also okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do this using the `XML` package in `R`. Here is the code

```
url = "http://www.consumercomplaints.in/bysubcategory/mobile-service-providers/page/1.html"
doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)

profiles = xpathSApply(doc, "//a[contains(@href, 'profile')]", xmlValue)
profiles = profiles[!(1:length(profiles) %% 2)]

states   = xpathSApply(doc, "//a[contains(@href, 'bystate')]", xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

This to match titles in blue bold, the trick is to open the source code of page and look what is before and after what are you looking for, then you use regex.

```
preg_match('/>[a-zA-Z0-9]+<\/a><\/h4><\/td>/', $str, $matches);
for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($matches);$i++)
 echo $matches[$i];
```

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735737/extract-data-php-string/5735958).